# How performance works in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance

I am solving https://8weeksqlchallenge.com/case-study-1/ last question and find two solution with the same results, but very different performance.
the second one is too slow, and i am curious to know why?

first solution:

```
SELECT
sales.customer_id,
sum(sales.point) as point
FROM
    (SELECT
        dannys_diner.sales.*,
        CASE
            WHEN dannys_diner.sales.order_date - dannys_diner.members.join_date >= 7 THEN dannys_diner.menu.price * 20
            WHEN 
                dannys_diner.sales.order_date - dannys_diner.members.join_date < 7 AND dannys_diner.menu.product_name = 'sushi'
            THEN dannys_diner.menu.price * 20
            ELSE dannys_diner.menu.price * 10
        END AS point
    FROM
        dannys_diner.sales
    right outer join
        dannys_diner.members
    on
        dannys_diner.sales.customer_id = dannys_diner.members.customer_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dannys_diner.menu
    on
        dannys_diner.sales.product_id = dannys_diner.menu.product_id) as sales
GROUP by sales.customer_id;
```

second solution:

```
SELECT
dannys_diner.sales.customer_id,
sum(CASE
    WHEN dannys_diner.sales.order_date - dannys_diner.members.join_date >= 7 
    THEN 
        (SELECT
            dannys_diner.menu.price * 20 AS point
        FROM
            dannys_diner.menu
        WHERE
            dannys_diner.menu.product_id = dannys_diner.sales.product_id)
    ELSE 
        (SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN dannys_diner.menu.product_name = 'sushi' THEN dannys_diner.menu.price * 20
                ELSE dannys_diner.menu.price * 10
            END AS point
        FROM
            dannys_diner.menu
        WHERE
            dannys_diner.menu.product_id = dannys_diner.sales.product_id)
END) AS point
FROM
    dannys_diner.sales
right outer join
    dannys_diner.members
on
    dannys_diner.sales.customer_id = dannys_diner.members.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dannys_diner.menu
on
    dannys_diner.sales.product_id = dannys_diner.menu.product_id
GROUP BY
    dannys_diner.sales.customer_id;
```

Comment: Check the [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Comment: The second uses 2 [correlated subqueries](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery). That should be harder to optimize compared to aggregating a normal subquery.

Comment: Btw, the 1st can even be simplified by summing the `CASE WHEN`.

Comment: I want like OOP and define some independent SELECT and check them independently, then use them in other places. @LukStorms

Comment: Well, SQL is a [declarative programming language](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming), so it's probably better not to think to much in the same ways as for other languages. But I guess that you'll like stuff like [CTE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cte/) or the [json](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/) stuff.